# how to add facebook's friends into iphone's address book

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, address-bar

I'm new in iPhone development. I want to add facebook's friends name into iPhone's address book.

I can get get facebook's friend list from the facebook using facebook's `sdk.framework`.

Can someone help me to insert this friends name into iPhone address book?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read Adress book programing from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

And for inserting contact: idea is -

You need make object of address book   `ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();`
then create a record like this  `ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();`

then set some property like this

`ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR(fbUserName), &anError);`

fbUserName is the name of your friend getting by fbGraph api.

then you need to insert this record in address book  `ABAddressBookAddRecord();`

then save the changes.   `ABAddressBookSave();`

at last

`CFRelease(addressBook);`

Comment: {
        birthday = "04/28/1987";
        "first_name" = Raghav;
        hometown =         {
            id = 109237889094394;
            name = Bhilai;
        };
I m getting this values.how can i insert this one into address book